# Can someone help me assign multiple string arrays into one 2d string array?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, variable-assignment

In C#, can someone help me assign multiple string arrays to a 2d string array?

Here is my code:

```
string[] test1 = new string[5] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
string[] test2 = new string[5] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
string[] test3 = new string[5] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };
string[] test4 = new string[5] { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" };

string[,] allTestStrings = new string [4, 5];
allTestStrings[0] = test1;
allTestStrings[1] = test2;
allTestStrings[2] = test3;
allTestStrings[3] = test4;
```

I am getting the following error for each 2d assignment:

> Wrong number of indices inside []; expected 2

What am I doing wrong in the above code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: a multidimensional array (`[,]`) is not a jagged array (`[],[]`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to specify both indicies for your 2D array, e.g.

```
allTestStrings[0, 0] = test1[0];
allTestStrings[0, 1] = test1[1];
```

You could extract a method to do this in a loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < test1.Length; i++)
{
    allTestStrings[0, i] = test1[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize it like this:

```
string[,] arr = {
                    { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" },
                    { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" },
                    { "one", "two", "three", "four", "five" },
                };
```

[MSDN: Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

you can use jagged array, Like this:

```
string[][] allTestStrings = new string[4][];
            allTestStrings[0] = test1;
            allTestStrings[1] = test2;
            allTestStrings[2] = test3;
            allTestStrings[3] = test4;
```